# MS Office Access from Python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc module to connect to MS access DB from python. However, the only driver available when i run the following command is SQL Server.

"pyodbc.drivers()"

Comment: Please describe clearly what you're trying to achieve and the problem encountered, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to write a good question likely to attract help.

Comment: Do you have MS Access Office app installed? Are you on a Windows machine which is the only way to connect to MS Access? You can download its ODBC drivers free online by Access version and CPU bit architecture (hop on search engine). Also, it is hard to below only *one* driver shows up with that output.

Comment: I have Office 365 ProPlus. Yes I am on the same Windows machine from which I want to Run Python as well as the MS access data. Can you suggest a link to download the driver?

Comment: @Parfait - A vanilla install of Windows will only have "SQL Server" in the list of 64-bit drivers. That implies that OP is running 64-bit Python and hence should install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine redistributable (if possible).